# Javascript linking plugin from zip file

Tags: javascript, plugins, popup, box

I have a problem where i want to install SmallPop plugin for javascript but im using website codepen, which requires me to give it a .html link, while the plugin is zip file, i couldn't find anywhere the link. Can I somehow link the zip file so everyone can see it on codepen.io ? I really need that popup plugin.

```
http://silvio-r.github.io/spop/#demo-basic
```

Link to the plugin.

Comment: Have you tried to use this URL? http://silvio-r.github.io/spop/dist/spop.min.js

Comment: How did you get it ? I tried so many times.